# Database doesn't load

Tags: php, mysql

I want to open a count in a php file in order to get the first register

```
<?php
include_once('dbConfig.php');
session_start();
$id_persona= $_SESSION["id"];


$query = "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS alias1 FROM  `desayuno_ingreso` WHERE  `desayuno_ingreso`.`id` =88757532";

echo $query;

$resultset = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultset) > 0){
$k=0;



while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {

                $lat[$k]= $fila['alias1'];

                $k=$k+1;
              }
              }

echo $lat[0];

?>
```

I tried in every single way I know (Every way worked for me before). However, it doesn't working right now.

I'm no sure what I'm doing wrong.

EIDTED
This is the dbConfig.php file:

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPass = 'mypassword';
$dbName = 'app';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass,$dbName);
if(!$conn){
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?  have you confirmed it's successfully connecting to the database?

Comment: What is in `dbConfig.php`?

Comment: I'm gonna update the post. dbConfig.php is a file where is the connection

Comment: I doesn't show any error. The id exists

Comment: try mysql instead of mysqli for test purpose, may be you haven't add the support for mysqli in your php.ini file @NyanMe

Comment: we have also seen that sometimes using 127.0.0.1 works instead of localhost

Comment: I changed localhost for 127.0.0.1 and it's woking right now! Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I close the topic?

Comment: Awesome, to close question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37752/how-do-i-close-my-own-question